# place a variable in the middle of a link in flash AS3

Tags: php, flash

here's what i'm trying to do.

I have a variable coming from a PHP file called `$sponny` (don't ask about the weird names)

I then send that variable to flash using the print function and call the variable in flash `userName`

now with all that gone well....

I would like to use that variable in flash (`userName`) inside a link which the user will be redirected to. so the link: `www.link.com/blah/blah/blah/userName`

I don't know how to insert the variable's value into a link...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('www.link.com/blah/blah/blah/'+userName));
```

Comment: but what if it's in the middle of the link? You've closed the quotes after "blah/" so what if i wanted the variable to be in the middle of the link (www.link.com/blah/userName/blah/blah)?

Comment: Then put a bit more text on the end: `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('www.link.com/blah/blah/blah/'+userName+'/blah/blah/'));`

Comment: just tried it. It now throws an error at me (access of undefined property userName. the error code is the link.

Comment: fairly self explanatory, that. `userName` is not defined in the same scope as the call to `navigateToURL`.  Please update your question with the code where you set `userName`.

Comment: variables.userName = event.target.data.return_sponsor_id; ^^^^^^^variable taken from php^^^^                           navigateToURL(new URLRequest('www.bbc.com/'+userName));
} ^^^^^navigating to the url^^^^ (just using bbc.com as an example)

Comment: So then it would be `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('www.link.com/blah/blah/blah/'+variables.userName+'/blah/blah/'));`